Dealing with transparent backgrounds when using framer motion
I am currently designing a UI for a website I am working on, and have an asset of a png with a transparent background. I can sucessfully make the background of the image appear transparent, but the "hitbox" includes the transparent background when using this Cursor  effect.
I want the effect to only be applied when the when the user's cursor hovers over the subject of the image (not the transparent pixels). To do this, do I need to use  or some other library? Thanks in advance
My existing code:
import React from "react";
import { Cursor } from "./cursorHover";

type ImageProps = React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> & {
  alt: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  hover?: JSX.Element;
};

const Image: React.FC<ImageProps> = (
  { alt, width, height, hover, ...props }: ImageProps,
  ref
) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      {hover && (
        <Cursor
          attachToParent
          variants={{
            initial: { height: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0.3 },
            animate: { height: "auto", opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
            exit: { height: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0.3 },
          }}
          transition={{
            type: "spring",
            duration: 0.3,
            bounce: 0.1,
          }}
          className="overflow-hidden"
        >
          {typeof hover === "boolean" ? <div>hi</div> : hover}
        </Cursor>
      )}
      <img {...props} alt={alt} width={width} height={height} />
      <canvas ref={ref} style={{ display: "none" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;


To apply the cursor effect only to non-transparent regions of the image, use the Cursor component's clipPath CSS property, which allows you to design a shape that masks an element's content.
Here's how you can modify your Image component to use clipPath:
JavaScript
import React from "react";
import { Cursor } from "./cursorHover";

type ImageProps = React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement> & {
  alt: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  hover?: JSX.Element;
};

const Image: React.FC<ImageProps> = (
  { alt, width, height, hover, ...props }: ImageProps,
  ref
) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      {hover && (
        <Cursor
          attachToParent
          variants={{
            initial: { height: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0.3 },
            animate: { height: "auto", opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
            exit: { height: 0, opacity: 0, scale: 0.3 },
          }}
          transition={{
            type: "spring",
            duration: 0.3,
            bounce: 0.1,
          }}
          className="overflow-hidden"
          style={{ clipPath: `url(#image-mask)` }}
        >
          {typeof hover === "boolean" ? <div>hi</div> : hover}
        </Cursor>
      )}
      <img {...props} alt={alt} width={width} height={height} />
      <canvas ref={ref} style={{ display: "none" }} />
      <svg width={width} height={height} style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, pointer-events: "none" }}>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="image-mask">
            <image href={props.src} width={width} height={height} xlinkHref={props.src} />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;

The clipPath element is created within the SVG, using the href attribute to reference the image.
The clipPath is applied to the Cursor component using the style={{ clipPath:url(#image-mask)}} property.
This effectively masks the Cursor component to only appear over the non-transparent parts of the image.
By making these changes, the cursor effect should now be applied only to the subject of the image, excluding the transparent background.
